# Can I seperate the values of a dictionary into multiple columns and still be able to plot them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, seaborn

I want to seperate the values of a dictionary into multiple columns and still be able to plot them. At this moment all the values are in one column. 
So concretely I would like to split all the different values in the list of values. And use the amount of values in the longest list as the amount of columns. So for all the shorter lists I would like to fill in the gaps with something like 'NA' so I can still plot it in seaborn.

This is the dictionary that I used:

```
dictio = {'seq_7009': [6236.9764, 6367.049999999999], 'seq_418': [3716.3642000000004, 3796.4124000000006], 'seq_9143_unamb': [4631.958999999999], 'seq_2888': [5219.3359, 5365.4089], 'seq_1101': [4287.7417, 4422.8254], 'seq_107': [5825.695099999999, 5972.8073], 'seq_6946': [5179.3118, 5364.420900000001], 'seq_6162': [5531.503199999999, 5645.577399999999], 'seq_504': [4556.920899999999, 4631.959], 'seq_3535': [3396.1715999999997, 3446.1969999999997, 5655.896546], 'seq_4077': [4551.9108, 4754.0073,4565.987654,5668.9999976], 'seq_1626_unamb': [3724.3894999999998]}
```

This is the code for the dataframe:

```
  df = pd.Series(dictio)
 test=pd.DataFrame({'ID':df.index, 'Value':df.values})


seq_107     [5825.695099999999, 5972.8073]
seq_1101    [4287.7417, 4422.8254]
seq_1626_unamb  [3724.3894999999998]
seq_2888    [5219.3359, 5365.4089]
seq_3535    [3396.1715999999997, 3446.1969999999997, 5655....
seq_4077    [4551.9108, 4754.0073, 4565.987654, 5668.9999976]
seq_418     [3716.3642000000004, 3796.4124000000006]
seq_504     [4556.920899999999, 4631.959]
seq_6162    [5531.503199999999, 5645.577399999999]
seq_6946    [5179.3118, 5364.420900000001]
seq_7009    [6236.9764, 6367.049999999999]
seq_9143_unamb  [4631.958999999999]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Value` column to a list of lists, and reload it into a new dataframe. Afterwards, call `plot`. Something like this -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test.Value.tolist(), index=test.ID)
df

                        0          1            2            3
ID                                                            
seq_107         5825.6951  5972.8073          NaN          NaN
seq_1101        4287.7417  4422.8254          NaN          NaN
seq_1626_unamb  3724.3895        NaN          NaN          NaN
seq_2888        5219.3359  5365.4089          NaN          NaN
seq_3535        3396.1716  3446.1970  5655.896546          NaN
seq_4077        4551.9108  4754.0073  4565.987654  5668.999998
seq_418         3716.3642  3796.4124          NaN          NaN
seq_504         4556.9209  4631.9590          NaN          NaN
seq_6162        5531.5032  5645.5774          NaN          NaN
seq_6946        5179.3118  5364.4209          NaN          NaN
seq_7009        6236.9764  6367.0500          NaN          NaN
seq_9143_unamb  4631.9590        NaN          NaN          NaN

df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you that's exactly what I needed! i'd upvote your answer if I would have enough  reputation...

Comment: @Reetveter199 Check again... ;-)